# Cannot connect to own Team Fortress 2 server

Tags: team-fortress-2, hosting

I have been following [this tutorial](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/13/828939163961292409/) to make my own TF2 server. And have gotten to video Sechs (six), and I have tried to connect to my own server by going to the server browser in TF2, but it says there are no servers on [my] current network. Everything has worked exactly as AVeryPatientPlayer said it should, except I cannot connect to my own server.

I have:

- Port Forwarded 27015 (I don't need to DMZ, since I have just one router; but this should affect me connecting to it on LAN)(Forcing the server to start on 25565 which has worked in the past for my MC server didn't change a thing)
- Done everything as the guy in the tutorial says I should.
- Made sure that I am using my ethernet IPv4 for everything, making sure not to use my wireless- even turning it off
- Added the sample server.cfg that is shown at the bottom of the tutorial page and changed a few values, such as server name and RCOn password.
- Added a custom mapcycle.txt

I have not:

- Installed any mods aside from SouceMod and MetaMod as in the tutorial
- Been able to find it on TF2's server browser "LAN" tab.

What first hinted to this problem for me (and why I decided to test connecting to it) is that every time during the tutorials, AVPP goes to his server "console" tab it says something about connected and the public IP. I looked at mine and it was just blank. It did respond when I typed in the commands "Meta version" as done in the tutorial.

Could someone help me? I would really like to get this server working so my friends and I can play together.

Comment: My server has now started crashing on Startup. As soon as it is done loading, it briefly shows the settings page, then crashes and vanishes. I have tried validating the download and it is all correct, according to SteamCMD.

Comment: Here is part of the log file: (version "2123087")
L 03/03/2014 - 17:10:29: server_cvar: "sv_tags" "Rotating voteformap,alltalk,mvm,norespawntime"
L 03/03/2014 - 17:10:29: server_cvar: "sv_tags" "Rotating voteformap,alltalk,mvm,norespawntime"
L 03/03/2014 - 17:10:29: Sending CMsgGameServerMatchmakingStatus (state=ServerMatchmakingState_NOT_PARTICIPATING)
L 03/03/2014 - 17:10:30: server_cvar: "sm_nextmap" "cp_dustbowl"
L 03/03/2014 - 17:10:30: [META] Loaded 0 plugins (1 already loaded)
L 03/03/2014 - 17:10:30: server_message: "quit"
L 03/03/2014 - 17:10:30: Log file closed

Comment: I believe such questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @AustinMohr I'm not sure how setting up a TF2 server would be off-topic; that plays right to our expertise.

Comment: Thank you @Frank. I just updated the server, with the new TF2 update today, and it is still crashing on startup. I'll try redownload the whole thing on the weekend. Note: In my previous comment, the log said "Meta" not "Arquade meta"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure what the cause of the "unable to connect" problem was, but I have updated my TF2 dedicated server files and now the console *does* show text once it has started and I, and my friends from their own houses, can connect. I do know, however, the reason that the server was crashing on startup. I was attempting to start the server on a MVM map, none of which are shown on the in-game level voting.

Thank you to those who have read and devoted some of your time to try help me solve this problem, even though it was not a problem we could have solved.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to use the command `connect localhost:27015` in the console. This should directly connect you to your server at your local IP. If you have a different port, replace the `27015` with whatever port you are using.

Comment: Thanks, but this has been resolved some time ago. Reading the answer I posted, it was because the server was crashing on startup - since I had it on an MvM map without the required player cap.

Comment: @Greatmar2 Oh, sorry. I just joined StackExcange a week ago, so I don't really know where to check stuff. Sorry about that.

Comment: Haha, no worries. Thanks for the effort, anyways. :)